# jQuery Accordion closes immediately it's opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion

I have modified some jQuery code for a site I'm working on which has an accordion menu.

```
$(function() {
    function close_accordion_section() {
        $('.accordion-section-title').removeClass('active');
        $('.accordion-section-content').slideUp(300).removeClass('open');
    }

    $('.accordion-section-title').click(function(e) {
        // Grab current anchor value
        var currentAttrValue = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(currentAttrValue);

        if($(e.target).is('.active')) {
            close_accordion_section();
        } else {

            // Add active class to section title
            $(this).addClass('active');
            // Open up the hidden content panel
            $(currentAttrValue).slideDown(300).addClass('open');
        }

        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```

The accordion should remain open until it's clicked again, but for some reason it's closing immediately after opening, a bit like it's on an elasticated leash.

I would much prefer if the accordion only closed when a user clicks it. I have reproduced the .html.erb file below.

```
<div class="copytext text-box col-5">

  <h2>Optimisation, Forecasting, Sales and Marketing Alignment</h2> 

  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#optimisation-accordbar">Optimisation</a>

    <div id="optimisation-accordbar" class="accordion-section-content">
      <p>In short, optimisation is getting the best out of what you have.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#margin-improvement-accordbar">Margin Improvement</a>

    <div id="margin-improvement-accordbar" class="accordion-section-content">
      <p>Margin improvement is about making more profit by improving what you already do.</p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="accordion-section">
    <a class="accordion-section-title" href="#forecasting-accordbar">Forecasting</a>

    <div id="forecasting-accordbar" class="accordion-section-content">
      <p>Forecasting is the act of getting the sales team to stop producing works of fantasy and produce figures which production believe enough to manufacture to.</p>
      <p>Aligning sales and marketing is ensuring that marketing activities are such that they drive the sales team towards their turnover targets but now, so that they drive the sales team to sell the products which make the company the greatest profit based on the mix of products they sell.</p>
      <p>We can address all of these areas without telling you about some new specialized piece of machinery would reduce faults, 
    make things faster and replace 5 shop floor operatives.</p>
      <p>In fact, our optimisation models often show that the introduction of an expensive but appropriate piece of automated production will indeed increase the profits as expected, but it often shows up the rather than dismissing the now unwanted labour, the firm can make even greater profits by redeploying them.<p/>
      <p>A sales plan or manufacturing plan or an investment justification plan cannot show the interactions which Linear Programming Optimisation can,
        and often to the shock of the accountants, a labour cost can be a large profit improvement if deployed wisely and modeled correctly.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The SCSS follows.

```
/* Transitions */

.accordion, .accordion * {
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; 
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box; 
    box-sizing:border-box;
}

.accordion {
    cursor: pointer;
    overflow:hidden;
    box-shadow:0px 1px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    border-radius:3px;
    background:#f7f7f7;
}

.accordion-section-title {
    width:100%;
    padding:15px;
    display:inline-block;
    background:#eee;
    @include default-border;
    transition:all linear 0.15s;
    font-size:1.200em;
    text-shadow:1px 1px 0px #555;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.accordion-section-title.active, .accordion-section-title:hover {
    background:#4c4c4c;
    text-decoration:none;
}

.accordion-section-content {
    padding:15px;
    display:none;
}
```

If anyone can help me work out what's going on and how to get the accordion to stay open until the user clicks on it again, I would be very grateful as I've been through various debugging steps and I still can't work out what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your issue is related to doing the same thing twice. Without loading any other library except `jQuery`, your code seems to [`work fine`](https://jsfiddle.net/websiter/2g6bo8wt/), except it wrongly closes all instances instead of just the current one, when you have more than one open and try to close any of them.

My best guess is you are loading some other script/library (possibly `jQuery-ui`?) which already provides the open/close functionality to the `class`es you use on your elements. So you have two options:

1. Roll with the current open/close functionality of whatever library you are using - this means giving up on your current custom animation.
2. Roll with your custom animation but use different class-names, so the library doesn't open/close them for you.

Comment: This definitely sounds like a very plausible cause. Just a minute while I check...

Comment: My advice is to roll with the built-in functionality of whatever you are using, ***using their markup*** (that's important), but that's me, always trying to get things done fast, with the least amount of effort. If you really want a custom animation effect, the choice is clearly yours.